# Remove #NULL! using Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm generating excel file by using SPSS and the excel contains character as #NULL! and as it is huge file it's difficult to remove with find & replace command how to do it by using macro

Thank you

Comment: Search on here - there are answers you can edit to your situation.

Comment: Have you tried the “record macro” route?

Comment: `it's difficult to remove with find & replace command` **[1.]** Start Recording a macro **[2.]** Press Ctrl + H **[3.]** Replace All `#NULL!` in one go with whatever you want **[4.]** Stop recording and check vba code. as simple as that...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub NullKiller()
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each r In rng
        If r.Text = "#NULL!" Then
            r.Clear
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```